# A "Julian" way of repeating elements in a given array

Tags: arrays, julia

Consider an array as the following:

```
[1,4,5,9]
```

The goal is to duplicate each value and append it next to it's copy in Julia, hence:

```
[1,1,4,4,5,5,9,9]
```

Is there a neat "julian" way of doing this avoiding a *for- loop*?

Comment: Haha, "julian" = elegant = your opinion ;)

Comment: Thanks! will delete this

Comment: Wait, @Wyck. Isn't the post you pasted related to Javascript and not Julia?

Comment: I added that I'm looking for code in Julia. Perhaps not writing this explicitly made things confusing. cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`repeat`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.repeat) function:

```
julia> v = [1, 4, 5, 9]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 4
 5
 9

julia> repeat(v; inner=2)
8-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 4
 4
 5
 5
 9
 9
```

Comment: very "julian", sir. Thank your.